# How to send json object from controller to html template in node.js?

Tags: node.js

Hi i am very new to node.js please help my problem.

This is my controller it have a search function i called this function from
   server.js this is captured json object from api.

And i want to send this object to html page i written code for that below.

i.e, res.render('display',....) but it gives an error.i.e undefined is not a 
   function.

please help me how to redirect html template with json object from a
   controller in node.js?

```
var storeJSONData;

exports.Search = function(req,res){

  var callback = function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
     // Your error handling here
     console.log(error);
    } else {
    // Your success handling here

    storeJSONData = JSON.parse(data);

    res.render('display', {
      jsonData: storeJSONData
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not setting up express correctly with your template engine.

Assuming you're using Express and Jade then passing a values (or the context) into a template is as follows;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// assuming your Search controller is in controllers/search
var searchCtrl = require('./controllers/search');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/search', searchCtrl);
```

Comment: var express=require('express');
    var app =express();

    var controller=require('./controllers/search');

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views')); 
    app.set('view engine', 'html');


    app.post('/search',function(req,res){

    controller.Search(req,res);


    });

Comment: @NagarjunaReddi Update your question with that code please. Also can you please tell me what line number are you getting the `undefined is not a function` ?

Comment: Actually i called controller from server.js file as i written the code in the second comment when i run the server it runs fine after enter the fields it redirects to search controller here the search function captures the json object from sabre api and i written the code for redirect to other html template for displaying json data

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at View.render (C:\Users\Desktop\sabre-dev-studio-node-master\n
ode_modules\express\lib\view.js:93:8)
at EventEmitter.app.render (C:\Users\Desktop\sabre-dev-studio-n
ode-master\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:530:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\Desktop\sabre-dev-studio
-node-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:933:7)
at callback (C:\Users\Desktop\sabre-dev-studio-node-master\cont
rollers\controller.js:34:7)
at C:\Users\Desktop\sabre-dev-studio-node-master\lib\sabre-dev-
studio.js:88:13
at passBackControl (C:\Users\Desktop\sabre-

Comment: @NagarjunaReddi My assumption is correct. You're not configuring the render engine for express correctly. This line `app.set('view engine', 'html'); ` you put in your comment is wrong. What template engine are you using ?

Comment: i am using html template. means with the extension of .html

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

or

```
app.register('.html', require('jade'));
```

Following example may help

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
controller = require('./controllers/search'); 

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile ); //in case of ejs

app.register('.html', require('jade')); //in case of jade

app.post('/search',function(req,res) { 
    controller.Search(req,res); 
});
```

Hope it helps